# How to serve angular2 app without browsersync

Tags: server, angular, lite-server

In my `package.json` I have the following:

```
...
"scripts": {
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "tsc:w": "tsc -w --outDir build",
        "lite": "lite-server",
        "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
    },
...
```

and I was wondering how could I start the app using "`npm production`" or something similar?

I'd want to prevent browsersync from running: I just tried with multiple users and it was hilarious to see that they were scrolling "as one". This also happens accross different browsers (but not using different tabs).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) instead of lite-server.

Comment: I did `npm install --save serve` and added the line `"serve": "serve",` under "scripts" in package.json. Then I was able to use `npm run serve`.

Comment: @PascalvKooten You can also install `serve` globally so that you do not have to keep a local copy in every project of yours. For this package, you will not require different versions across multiple projects.

Comment: How to run it without node or npm or browser-sync??

Comment: you should use another web server if don't want to use node and npm

Comment: But with npm serve, when i refresh none-root pages, it's a 404.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `npm start`.
In newly installed Angular app with `ng new <name_of_app>`, the package.json file has the settings for that

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```

So using `npm start` will run `ng serve` and the browser sync does not run browsersync

Answer (score -1):

you can use http-server `(npm install -g http-server`)
then in your project directory `http-serve -p [port]`