# Angular - session seems to be shared across all users. What would cause that?

Tags: angular, session

Using Angular for a new app, and I'm experiencing some really unexpected behavior. With two different test machines, going to the login page and typing in the form, the typing is synchronized between the two browsers, on different test machines. What would cause a session to be shared across multiple browsers, on different test machines? Each keypress seems to happen on both when filling out forms, and with one session logged in on test machine one, clicking log out on machine 2 causes the other test machine to log out. I see no network activity in the chrome inspector. Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36601217/how-to-serve-angular2-app-without-browsersync

Comment: Are you using Angular Fire + Reactive Forms - so getting real time updates, not session .. It sounds like an Observable thing...

Comment: It was browsersync. Many thanks for the help. If you add it as an answer I'll accept!